# Custom php code in joomla component , pages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

How can we use php code in joomla.Like any available component , plugin , module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take this component for refrence.
http://code.google.com/p/joomla-php/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jumi, it's a plugin/component/module that allows you to do precisely that.

Link: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023

Answer (score 1):

Always search for Extension in http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions.
There are  couple of Extension like [Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023), [PHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5057) ,[DirectPHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/4470) ,[Add PHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/60), [Include PHP](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/2921) and [so on](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content) that you can use

Answer (score 0):

And think of the disabling the filtering of code within Joomla. Joomla and the Edtior you use proably filter the code when you save.

> Configure Joomla! Article filters
>
> By default Joomla!  'cleans' content on saving, removing script tags,
>   event attributes (such as onclick, onmouseover etc.) and style tags.
>
> A simple article parameter change is all that is required to fix this.
>
> Joomla! 1.5
>
> See this article -
>   http://docs.joomla.org/Why_does_some_HTML_get_removed_from_articles_in_version_1.5.8%3F
>
> Joomla! 1.7
>
> In the Joomla! Article Manager, click on the Options button
>   In the Options Dialog, click on the Text Filters tab.
>   For the Super Users group, or any other trusted user group, set Filter Type to No Filtering. Make sure that you only set this option
>   for user groups that can be trusted as setting the Filter Type to No
>   Filtering will essentially allow the user to include any html in an
>   article.
>
> Joomla! 2.5
>
> In the Joomla! Global Configuration, click on the Text Filters tab.
>   For the Super Users group, or any other trusted user group, set Filter Type to No Filtering. Make sure that you only set this option
>   for user groups that can be trusted as setting the Filter Type to No
>   Filtering will essentially allow the user to include any html in an
>   article.

and the Editor (JCE)

> In the JCE Control Panel, click on the Editor Profiles button.
>
> Click on the Profile name that the user, usergroup or component is
>   assigned to, eg: 'Default'
>
> Click on the Editor Parameters tab, then on the Options tab.
>
> Check that the Allow Javascript or Allow CSS or Allow PHP options are
>   set to Yes (depending on which code type you need to insert).